# Style error in tag creation message

Tags: bug, status-completed, grammar

When trying to create a tag that too closely matches an existing tag a user receives the following error message:

```
You are attempting to create the tag [tag-1] ; however the tag [tag-2] already exists
```

The semicolon should not have a space before it in that message.

Comment: Reference? I think everyone knows there's not supposed to be a space there. I don't think anyone cares, though.

Comment: Really? 5 second fix - makes the world a tiny tiny bit better, or would you prefer these things never be pointed out?

Comment: Interesting, a space is required before and after every semicolon in the french language, I wonder why it isn't the same for english language... Anyway, question without any other interest.

Answer (score 5):

This was one of the less exciting bugs I tackled today, but it's fixed in the next build anyway.